# IdlingResources doesn't work Espresso Android

Tags: android, android-studio, testing, android-espresso

I have the problem with idling resources while testing using `Espresso`.

It doesn't work. It is called only twice and that's all, even if return `false`.

```
public class MyIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {

    private boolean mIdle;
    private ResourceCallback mResourceCallback;

    public MyIdlingResource () {
        this.mIdle = false;
        this.mResourceCallback = null;
    }

    @Override
    public final String getName() {
        return MyIdlingResource .class.getSimpleName();
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean isIdleNow() {
        ArrayList<View> views = doStuff();
        mIdle =  views != null && !views.isEmpty();

        if (mIdle) {
            if (mResourceCallback != null) {
                mResourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        mResourceCallback = resourceCallback;
    }

}
```

So in this case I return `false` all the time, but it doesn't work either.

What is wrong ?

Comment: You seem to be mutating state in what is typically the read-only getter isIdleNow method. I recommend you manage idling state in an explicit increment/decrement call, like this example from Google: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/contrib/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/CountingIdlingResource.java

Answer (score 1):

You missed `return true;` in below peace of code:

```
if (mIdle) {
    if (mResourceCallback != null) {
        mResourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
        return true; // this one is missed
    }
}
```